# Subsetting rows in data.table beloging to group by conditions

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have the following data.table that represents a “full pedigree”

```
full_pedigree <- data.table::fread("ID dad mum
81   0   0
 1   0   0 
 2   0   0 
 3   0   0 
 4   0   0 
 5   2   1 
 6   4   3 
 7   5   6 
 8   5  81 
 9   8   3 
10   8   3 
11   8   6 
12   8   6"
)
```

Next, I will create the “cross” field by the function makeCross so that cross = mumxdad or cross = dadxmum.

```
# function to create "cross" field 
makeCross <- function(pedigree) {
  ped.cross <- copy(pedigree)
  ped.cross[, cross := ifelse((mum == 0L | dad == 0L), NA,
      paste(pmin(mum, dad),
        pmax(mum, dad),
        sep = "x"
      ))]
  ped.cross[, cross := factor(cross,
    levels = unique(cross)
  )]
  return(ped.cross)
}
```

On the other hand, in a “family pedigree”, the target is to retain at least one individual for each family. However, if we have "n" individuals in the same family that also appears as parents in future generations, we also must keep them.
Here is my better attempt to create a “family pedigree” from a “full pedigree”

```
pedFam <- function(pedigree) {
    library(data.table, quietly = TRUE)

    # copy the pedigree to avoid side effects
    ped2 <- copy(pedigree)
    
    # remove the individuals with no cross
    ped <- makeCross(ped2)[!is.na(cross), ]
    setkey(ped, cross)
    ped <- ped[, .SD[1L], by = key(ped)]
    # identify which individuals will be represent each family
    id.keep <- ped[, ID]

    # function to prune the pedigree but retaining the key ancestors (parents)
    cutPed <- function(pedigree, id.keep) {
        ped.tmp <- copy(pedigree)
        n.id <- length(id.keep) + 1L
        while (length(id.keep) != n.id) {
            n.id <- length(id.keep)
            id.keep <- union(na.omit(c(unlist(ped.tmp[,.(mum, dad)][match(id.keep, ped.tmp[, ID]), ]))), id.keep)
        }
        ped.tmp <- ped.tmp[sort(match(id.keep, ped.tmp[, ID])), ]
        return(ped.tmp)
    }
    pedfam <- cutPed(pedigree = ped2, id.keep = id.keep)
    return(pedfam)
}
```

By using function pedFam() with the previous “full_pedigree” we get

```
pedfam <- pedFam(full_pedigree)
> pedfam
        ID dad mum
 1:     81   0   0
 2:      1   0   0
 3:      2   0   0
 4:      3   0   0
 5:      4   0   0
 6:      5   2   1
 7:      6   4   3
 8:      7   5   6
 9:      8   5  81
10:      9   8   3
11:     11   8   6
```

In this case, the function pedFam() work fine. However, for the next pedigree (“full_ped2”)

```
full_ped2 <- data.table::fread("ID mum dad 
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 1 2
6 1 2
7 3 4
8 3 4
9 6 7
10 6 7
11 6 7
12 8 11"
)
```

[image: graphical representation of full_ped2]

In this new pedigree, individuals 1 and 2 are crossed to form the family 1x2, which has two childs: 5 and 6. Then, we must select one of them to represent this family (1x2). In this case, only child 6 is kept because it becomes a parent of individuals 9, 10, and 11 (from family 6x7 in the next generation). In the same way, we must select at least one child to represent this family (6x7), and because individual 11 forms a new family with individual 8 (11x8), we select this child (11) to represent the family 11x8. Hence, from this pedigree ("full_ped2"), the expected result is

```
> pedfam
   ID mum dad
1:  1   0   0
2:  2   0   0
3:  3   0   0
4:  4   0   0
5:  6   1   2
6:  7   3   4
7:  8   3   4
8: 11   6   7
9: 12   8  11
```

Any help to fix the pedFam() function will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: forgive me, but this is quite long and complicated, and looking at your code without really knowing about animal breeding, it's hard to know how it all works. How did you get 28  15  19 for the last row for "full_ped2"?

Comment: Hi Mark, I changed the full_ped2 example for a more simplified version, and I have also added a figure that summarizes the evolution of this pedigree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `data.table`-based way of doing it:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

child_bearers <- melt(full_ped2, id.vars = "ID") %>%
    .[ID %in% value,] %>%
    dcast(ID ~ variable, value.var = "value")

first_children <- full_ped2 %>%
    .[,c("ID", "dad", "mum")] %>%
    .[, ID := first(ID), by = .(dad, mum)] %>%
    unique() # if you have the tidyverse packages loaded, this will convert the data.table into a dataframe annoyingly. I haven't been able to find a way around this

ped_fam <- merge(first_children, child_bearers, by = c("dad", "mum"), all.x = TRUE) %>%
    .[, ID := ifelse(is.na(ID.y), ID.x, ID.y)] %>%
    .[, ID.x := NULL] %>%
    .[, ID.y := NULL]

   dad mum ID
1:   0   0  1
2:   0   0  2
3:   0   0  3
4:   0   0  4
5:   2   1  6
6:   4   3  7
7:   4   3  8
8:   7   6 11
9:  11   8 12
```

And here's a `tidyverse`-based way of doing it:

```
# first, we find the necessary individuals- the ones who had kids
child_bearers <- full_ped2 %>%
    # make the data long
    pivot_longer(cols = c(dad, mum), names_to = "parent", values_to = "ID_parent") %>%

    # find the individuals who had kids
    filter(ID %in% ID_parent) %>%

    # then make it wide again
    pivot_wider(names_from = parent, values_from = ID_parent)

# next, we find the first kid of each couple
first_children <- full_ped2 %>% 
    select(mum, dad, ID) %>%
    group_by(mum, dad) %>%

    # unsure how this picks, you may want to change this if there's another method you'd prefer
    summarise(ID = first(ID))

# finally, we combine the two dataframes
ped_fam <- first_children %>%
    left_join(child_bearers, by = c("mum", "dad")) %>%

    # if a couple in the first_children dataframe didn't have a child who was themselves a parent, we include their first child instead
    mutate(ID.y = ifelse(is.na(ID.y), ID.x, ID.y)) %>%

    # remove the first_children ID column now we are done with it
    select(-ID.x, ID = ID.y) %>%
    ungroup()
    
# A tibble: 9 × 3
    mum   dad    ID
  <int> <int> <int>
1     0     0     1
2     0     0     2
3     0     0     3
4     0     0     4
5     1     2     6
6     3     4     7
7     3     4     8
8     6     7    11
9     8    11    12
```

Comment: Hi Mark, many thanks for your help! I have validated your code using a large pedigree (many generations), and it works perfectly!